# Computer Blue Screen From ntoskrnl.exe

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, motherboard, bsod

Recently iv been getting a blue screen of death at random times.. well i think, i haven't timed it. I used some software to read the crash dump and it this is what came out: ntoskrnl.exe  ntoskrnl.exe+3e1348 fffff801`1f008000   fffff801`1f891000   0x00889000  0x59ae237e  05/09/2017 05:09:34 
The mini dump download [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-yRjHNTkN_Va3lLVmtwOUctRnc)
if any one knows how to fix it please help!! i need this computer working.
Specs are:

1. windows 10
2. Evga gtx 1060 3g sc
3. core I3 7100 kaby with stock cooler
4. MSI 911-7A71-001 MSI Z270 A PRO Kaby Lake CrossFire ATX Motherboard - Black
5. Ram 8GB
6. 1TB Hard drive

Comment: share the dmp files from **C:\windows\minidump**

Comment: https://goo.gl/dwbNZE

Comment: I've posted an answer. install latest WIFI driver to fix the crash. If the new driver fixed the issue, you can [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), shows that the Atheros WIFI driver (from 2013) causes the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, A single DPC or ISR exceeded its time allotment. The offending
    component can usually be identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000501, The DPC time count (in ticks).
Arg3: 0000000000000500, The DPC time allotment (in ticks).
Arg4: fffff8011f3e9348, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
    additional information regarding this single DPC timeout

Debugging Details:
------------------

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: TickPeriods                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.608 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  MS-7A71

SYSTEM_SKU:  Default string

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1.10

BIOS_DATE:  02/03/2017

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z270-A PRO (MS-7A71)

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 501

BUGCHECK_P3: 500

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff8011f3e9348

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  SINGLE_DPC_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: f48

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,9e,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 48'00000000 (cache) 48'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  UE4Editor.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.16299.15 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8011f1a4568 to fffff8011f174580

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KeAccumulateTicks
02 nt!KeClockInterruptNotify
03 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt
04 nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
05 nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw
06 nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw
07 athwbx

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
athwbx+c7c62
fffff801`22567c62 4883c448        add     rsp,48h

IMAGE_NAME:  athwbx.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x133_DPC_athwbx!unknown_function

---------

0: kd> lmvm athwbx
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff801`224a0000 fffff801`2285f000   athwbx   T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: athwbx.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\athwbx.sys
    Image name: athwbx.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov 13 09:05:17 2013 (528332BD)
    CheckSum:         003BF901
    ImageSize:        003BF000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

So [install the last drivers](https://www.ath-drivers.eu/atheros-wireless-drivers.html) and hope it is fixed.

Comment: Im using a TP-LINK n900 Model:WDN4800 so what driver would i have to download and i havent had a crash in a week now so i dunno was it one time thing or not

Comment: this card should use the AR9380. so get this driver: https://www.ath-drivers.eu/download-driver-for-Atheros-chipset-with-id-65-and-Windows10-64bit.html

Comment: Iv installed driver but while i was doing it i noticed that the PCI simple communications controller has no driver

Comment: [this is Intel Management Engine (Intel ME)](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005754/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) . ignore this.